# How do I convert a string to a slice in a Golang struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to convert one of the string type fields in my struct to a slice.

I am using GORM to query. The field in question is stored as a JSON type in MySQL.

Here is an example of the stored JSON in one of the DB records:

```
[“tag1”, “tag2”, “tag3”]
```

My struct in Golang:

```
type Mystruct struct {
   Id int
   Name string
   Desc string
   Tags string // this is problem
}
```

I generate my struct like so:

```
mystruct := []Mystruct{}
db.Find(&mystruct)
```

Everything works fine except I would like “Tags” to be a slice, not a string. GORM throws an error if I use

```
Tags []string
```

I have also tried doing

```
Tags datatypes.JSON
```

included with GORM but that returns only bytes.

I essentially want to access and loop through Tags in a html template.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If it's JSON, use `encoding/json`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do so? I’m new to Golang and I’m having a lot of trouble with this. Do I need to use the scanner to convert it to JSON?

Comment: There are hundreds of questions on SO about using JSON in Go, and probably thousands of relevant links on Google. What happens when you search?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `db.Find(&mystruct)` to do the unmarshaling you'll have to use a custom type that implements the [`Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner) interface.

For example

```golang
type StringSlice []string

func (ss *StringSlice) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    switch data := src.(type) {
    case []byte:
        return json.Unmarshal(data, ss)
    case string:
        return json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), ss)
    }
    return nil // or an error
}
```

then update your type

```golang
type Mystruct struct {
   Id   int
   Name string
   Desc string
   Tags StringSlice
}
```

and if you use `Mystruct` for `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, then you'll also have to implement the [`Valuer`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) interface, otherwise saving of such an instance might break.

```golang
func (ss StringSlice) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return json.Marshal(ss)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: “syntax error: cannot use data := src.([]byte) as value”

Comment: my bad, that should've been a type switch. fixed

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I first got another error about unsupported datatype but adding a gorm tag (gorm:”type:text”) did the trick! Thanks